# How to measure the trainign time of KNN classifier training in C++ and OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, classification, knn

I'm using `CvKNearest` for `KNN` classification. I want to measure the time it takes for training. Here is the code :

```
#include <time.h>
clock_t start, end;
double time;
start = clock();
KnnClassifier.train( trainData, classes, Mat(), false, 1 );
end = clock();
time = ((float) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
cout<<" Training time (s) =   "<<time << "\n";
```

The problem is that the result is 0 seconds it takes for training.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe it indeed takes roughly 0s, how about you print time in micro-seconds, i.e., `time = 1000.0f * ((float) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;`?

Comment: The result is also 0. 
`start` and `end` are always equal !

Comment: What's the type of `time`? Can you show your full code?

Comment: Does `KnnClassifier.train` use GPU?

Answer (score 1):

If available (C++11) you could use chrono.

```
#include <chrono>

auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
KnnClassifier.train( trainData, classes, Mat(), false, 1 );
auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
cout << " Training time (s) = " << time.count() << "\n";
```

Comment: Is there any solution other than using C++11?

Comment: Do you have an idea of how long the training process is taking? The trouble with `clock()` is its poor granularity, if the process takes less than ~20ms (though this is completely architecture independent), then it may report back a run time of 0. There are libraries available, for example, boost's [ptime](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html), though I have no experience with them.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old but the posted answer in my opinion is not what should be used when working with OpenCV.

To measure time of an operation, OpenCV provides functions to do that. You can consult [official documentation for that](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#ga705441a9ef01f47acdc55d87fbe5090c).
Here's the code to write:

```
double t = (double)getTickCount();
// do something ...
t = ((double)getTickCount() - t)/getTickFrequency();
```

Another way is use `TickMeter` object in OpenCV.
Here's a description of `TickMeter` class from official documentation also:

> a Class to measure passing time.
>
> The class computes passing time by counting the number of ticks per
>   second. That is, the following code computes the execution time in
>   seconds:
>
> ```
> TickMeter tm;
> tm.start();
> // do something ...
> tm.stop();
> std::cout << tm.getTimeSec();
> ```
>
> It is also possible to compute the average time over multiple runs:
>
> ```
> TickMeter tm;
> for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
> {
>     tm.start();
>  // do something ...
>     tm.stop();
> }
> double average_time = tm.getTimeSec() / tm.getCounter();
> std::cout << "Average time in second per iteration is: " << average_time << std::endl;
> ```